# Oracle SQL: Exclude Rows Where TimeStamps are within minutes of each other

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a table of transactions.  I need to exclude any transactions that are within 15 minutes of the previous transaction for the same USER ID.

EXAMPLE

```
USERID          TRANS_TIME  
----------------------------------------  
00000001    24-FEB-17 15.13.51.713000000
00000001    16-MAR-17 10.10.20.781000000
00000001    16-MAR-17 10.10.32.659000000
00000001    16-MAR-17 10.13.04.070000000
00000001    16-MAR-17 10.13.49.339000000
00000001    16-MAR-17 10.22.33.467000000
00000001    16-MAR-17 10.23.09.755000000
00000001    16-MAR-17 10.25.51.994000000
00000001    16-MAR-17 10.26.08.130000000
00000001    29-MAR-17 10.23.01.665000000
```

So I would end up with 4 rows.

```
USER ID         TRANS_TIME  
----------------------------------------  
00000001    24-FEB-17 15.13.51.713000000
00000001    16-MAR-17 10.10.20.781000000
00000001    16-MAR-17 10.25.51.994000000
00000001    29-MAR-17 10.23.01.665000000
```

Any ideas or tips on how to code for this?  Ideally without creating a function or a procedure.

Cheers.

Comment: Is it oracle or mssql? Can't be both

Comment: Why do you show `16-MAR-17 10.25.51.994000000`? Previous transaction `16-MAR-17 10.23.09.755000000` is within 15 minutes.

Comment: What version of Oracle do you use? **Always** include that info; it is especially important in your problem, since it can be solved almost trivially in Oracle 12 but it is quite a bit harder in Oracle 11 and below.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - assuming the desired output is correct, the OP did not explain the problem very well. The logic is based on "windows" or "sessions" - for each row included in the output, exclude all rows that follow within 15 minutes **of that row** (not within 15 minutes of the immediately preceding one). If one row starts a session at 10:00, then a row at 10:14 is in the same session (and probably 10:15 also in the same session) but 10:15:01 is definitely in a different session - either one it starts itself or perhaps in a sessions started by another row at 10:15:00.327

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpreting your required logic as follows:

Separately for each `userid`, **include** the row with the earliest transaction time. Then, for each row, look to see if it is within 15 minutes (<=) of the most recent included row, and if it is, then exclude this "current" row you are examining. If the new row is **not** within 15 minutes of the most recently included row, then **include** this new row.

In other words, there are 15 minute sessions. A row opens a new session if it is not already in a session opened by another row. In this arrangement, as demonstrated by your desired output, it is not enough to compare a row to the one immediately preceding it.

This problem can be solved very easily with the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clause in Oracle 12.1 and above. Alas, this is not available in Oracle 11 or earlier.

```
with
     test_data ( userid, trans_time ) as (
       select '00000001', to_timestamp('24-FEB-17 15.13.51.713000000', 'dd-MON-yy hh24.mi.ss.ff') from dual union all
       select '00000001', to_timestamp('16-MAR-17 10.10.20.781000000', 'dd-MON-yy hh24.mi.ss.ff') from dual union all
       select '00000001', to_timestamp('16-MAR-17 10.10.32.659000000', 'dd-MON-yy hh24.mi.ss.ff') from dual union all
       select '00000001', to_timestamp('16-MAR-17 10.13.04.070000000', 'dd-MON-yy hh24.mi.ss.ff') from dual union all
       select '00000001', to_timestamp('16-MAR-17 10.13.49.339000000', 'dd-MON-yy hh24.mi.ss.ff') from dual union all
       select '00000001', to_timestamp('16-MAR-17 10.22.33.467000000', 'dd-MON-yy hh24.mi.ss.ff') from dual union all
       select '00000001', to_timestamp('16-MAR-17 10.23.09.755000000', 'dd-MON-yy hh24.mi.ss.ff') from dual union all
       select '00000001', to_timestamp('16-MAR-17 10.25.51.994000000', 'dd-MON-yy hh24.mi.ss.ff') from dual union all
       select '00000001', to_timestamp('16-MAR-17 10.26.08.130000000', 'dd-MON-yy hh24.mi.ss.ff') from dual union all
       select '00000001', to_timestamp('29-MAR-17 10.23.01.665000000', 'dd-MON-yy hh24.mi.ss.ff') from dual
     )
-- End of test data (not part of the solution). SQL query begins below this line.
select userid, session_start as trans_time
from   test_data
match_recognize (
  partition by userid
  order by     trans_time
  measures     a.trans_time as session_start
  pattern      ( a b* )
  define       b as b.trans_time <= a.trans_time + interval '15' minute
)
order by userid, trans_time    --   if needed
;

USERID    TRANS_TIME             
--------  ------------------------------
00000001  24-FEB-2017 15.13.51.713000000
00000001  16-MAR-2017 10.10.20.781000000
00000001  16-MAR-2017 10.25.51.994000000
00000001  29-MAR-2017 10.23.01.665000000
```

Comment: Thanks again for the answer.  Any chance you can explain the logic behind the measures, pattern and define syntax?

Comment: @AM84 - I could, but I would just repeat what is in the Oracle documentation. Assuming you are using Oracle 12.1 or higher (you probably are, if you were able to use this solution), you will find `match_recognize` to be an incredibly useful tool. It will help you tremendously to spend a little time to learn it. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm#DWHSG8956

Answer (score 1):

Just use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(trans_time) over (partition by userid order by trans_time) as prev_tt
      from t
     ) t
where prev_tt is null or
      trans_time > prev_tt + (15 / (24 * 60));
```

Note:  You can write the `where` using `interval` notation instead (that is actually a better approach):

```
where prev_tt is null or
      trans_time > prev_tt + interval '15' minute;
```

Comment: Considering the OP's output, it is likely that the logic wasn't explained very well. I explained the logic (what I believe the OP meant, anyway) in a Comment under the original post. If I am right, the problem is more interesting, and more difficult.

Comment: @mathguy you are correct, I did not explain the logic very well but you did get the idea.  Both answers below work a dream.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the same assumptions I made in my other answer (using the MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause), here is another way to solve the problem.

This solution uses recursive subquery factoring (recursive CTE), and therefore will work in Oracle 11.2 (but, unfortunately, not in earlier versions).

```
with
-- Begin test data (not part of the solution)
     test_data ( userid, trans_time ) as (
       [     select ......    SAME AS IN THE OTHER ANSWER     ]
     ),
-- End of test data (not part of the solution). SQL query begins below this line.
     prep ( userid, trans_time, rn ) as (
       select userid, trans_time, 
              row_number() over (partition by userid order by trans_time)
       from   test_data
     ),
     rec ( userid, trans_time, rn, session_start ) as (
       select     userid, min(trans_time), 1, min(trans_time)
         from     prep
         group by userid
       union all
         select   p.userid, p.trans_time, p.rn,
                  case when p.trans_time > r.session_start + interval '15' minute
                       then p.trans_time
                       else r.session_start
                  end
         from     prep p join rec r on p.userid = r.userid and p.rn = r.rn + 1
     )
select   distinct userid, trans_time
from     rec
where    trans_time = session_start
order by userid, trans_time       --   if needed
;
```